# Operador ~NOT en JavaScritp (ejemplos de uso basicos)

Tags: javascript, operador

Como entender con ejemplos de uso sencillos el operador **BItwise** **~NOT**?
entenderlo como si le quisieras eseñar a alguien que hasta ahora esta aprendiendo sobre operadores **bit a bit** en Javascript

Gracias!

Comment: en un tiempo usarlo doble `~~` era mas rápido que `Math.floor` para descartar los decimales

Answer (score 2):

Por darte un ejemplo, primeramente debes manejar muy bien eso de las representaciones binarias:
Si le aplicas NOT al numero 2

```
var numDos= ~2;
```

En binario el dos es 010, y lo que hace el NOT es invertir los bits, o sea tenemos al reves: 101. Esto te devuelve -3
Otro ejemplo:

```
var numDiez= ~10;
```

Esto devuelve -11. Partimos de que 10 en binario es  0000001010. E invirtiendo los bits quedan:  1111110101, esto es -11.
No te preocupes por la representacion de numeros negativos es solo una notacion.
Lo que si debes saber es, al aplicar el NOT a cualquier numero, llamemosle X. Lo que obtendras es siempre un numero X+1 negativo, es decir -(x+1).

```
Aplicas not al numero -16, tienes -(-16+1) = 15
Al numero 18 por ejemplo, - (18+1) -19
```

Y asi..

Comment: Aún no me queda claro el porque de los 32 bits,  pero creo que me faltava leerlo desde otro angulo para entenderlo. De verdad gracias!